# How do I get my bot to wait for reply from a mentioned user discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I would like my bot to wait for a response in chat from only the user that was mentioned in the command.

This is how it is supposed to work:

1. I send `&tictactoe @someuser#1234`
2. The bot responds with:

```
nathen418 wants to play a game of Tic-Tac-Toe with you. Do you accept?
Yes or No
```

3. @someuser#1234 types `Yes` or `No`
4. The bot responds with either `They want to play Tic-Tac-Toe with you!` or `They did not want to play with you. :(`

This works correctly if I @ mention myself(`@nathen418#0002`). But if I send the command `&tictactoe @someuser#1234` and `@someuser#1234` tries to respond, the bot ignores them. I want the bot to only listen for `Yes` or `No` from the user that I mentioned

This Is my code:

```js
const exceptionHandler = require('../handlers/exceptionHandler');
const logToConsole = require('../events/logToConsole');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    tictactoeCMD: function (message, bot) {
        const member = message.mentions.members.first().id;
        message.channel.send(message.author.username + " wants to play a game of Tic-Tac-Toe with you. Do you accept?\n `Yes` or `No`")
        console.log(message.author.id)
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { time: 10000 });
        collector.on('collect', message => {

                console.log(message.author.id)
                console.log("^ message author Below member id")
                console.log(member)
                if (message.author.id === member && message.content.toUpperCase() == "YES") {
                    message.reply(" they want to play Tic-Tac-Toe with you!");
                } else if (message.author.id === member && message.content.toUpperCase() == "NO") {
                    message.reply( " They did not want to play with you. :(");
                }
        })
        //logToConsole.command(message.guild, message);
    }
}
```

This is what happens when I run the bot:
[image: Output of my code running]

The full code is available on the `alpha` branch in github: https://github.com/Antares-Network/AntaresBot/tree/alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're currently doing is you're requesting input from the **message's author**.
Seeing as you're interested in getting the mentioned member's input, you'd want to compare the collected message author's id to the member id you've defined as `member` earlier.

#### Final code:

```
onst exceptionHandler = require('../handlers/exceptionHandler');
const logToConsole = require('../events/logToConsole');

const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    tictactoeCMD: function (message, bot) {
        const member = message.mentions.members.first().id;
        message.channel.send(message.author.username + " wants to play a game of Tic-Tac-Toe with you. Do you accept?\n `Yes` or `No`")
        console.log(message.author.id)
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === member, { time: 10000 }); // <--- Line edited
        collector.on('collect', message => {
            console.log(message.author.id)
            console.log("^ message author Below member id")
            console.log(member)
            if (message.author.id === member && message.content.toUpperCase() == "YES") {
                message.reply(" they want to play Tic-Tac-Toe with you!");
            } else if (message.author.id === member && message.content.toUpperCase() == "NO") {
                message.reply( " They did not want to play with you. :(");
            }
    })
    //logToConsole.command(message.guild, message);
  }
}
```